# What type of wall anchors to use on a prefabricated sunroom wall made of metal with foam insulation?

Tags: walls, anchor, prefab

I have a prefabricated, four season sunroom. The walls are made of metal (I think) and have foam insulation. What kinds of wall anchors can I use?

Comment: Will need how the walls are made, what weight you expect to hold, and if the thing is expensive.  Usually the more weight and cost of the thing, the less anchors are recommended.  Thin metal and/or drywall do not have too much holding power for heavy(30 plus pounds) breakable objects.

Comment: There are probably metal studs, if you need to hang something heavy...

Answer (score 1):

In many/most cases, none. The wall structure in a prefab built that way is likely *just about able to hold itself*, and not much more.

For very light things, if you have a sheet metal wall surface, you could use short sheet metal screws. Then again, double-sided tape or poster adhesive will work for the class of things light enough to hang there and not involve holes in the wall surface.

If you want something heavy (or shelves) to be in front of the wall, park a shelving unit that **self-supports from the floor** in front of the wall and put the heavy thing(s) on it.

Comment: **sheet metal screws** +1. If those aren't good enough to hold it, then it can go there.

Answer (score 0):

Every answer about hanging something comes back to how heavy the item is that will be hung.  Lightweight items can hang in places where heavy items cannot.  Solutions that are more robust are preferred, but where they cannot be applied, failure prone solutions might be ok.

Your paneling is likely light weight aluminum (or similar) cladding.  Thin sheets of metal bend.  The goal it to get it not to bend, so the goal is to limit the weight, increase the points of contact, and spread the load across enough surface area that the sheet doesn't bend.  Hanging something is dead weight, so any solution will have to be capable of holding more weight than you will use, to avoid bending over time.

So, start off by seeing if there are metal studs behind the skin.  This will give more layers of metal, but more importantly it will give L or C shaped channels, where the stress on the metal will resist deforming.  If you drill through the sheeting and a stud, and use an expansion bolt (molly bolt), the stress is spread across more metal. You then are less likely to encounter problems for light weight items.

For very light items, double sticky foam tape has advantages because the foam tape will fail before the wall is damaged.  Of course, this comes with the downside of seeing your item drop to the floor.

For anything that is heavy (10+ lbs) I would avoid the panels and install a picture rail (a metal bar) near the ceiling, where it is mounted to the wall's framing.  It's like a curtain rod, but closer to the wall, so it can take more load.  Pictures hang from wires attached to hooks that hang on the bar.  This approach can even work in front of glass windows (making framed stained glass look fantastic).  The advantage is that you get to relocate the hanging problems to the structure's framing, which can hold more load.

If you have unsuitable location that is exactly where you want the picture, exotic (aka expensive) solutions come into play.  They involve reinforcing the skin cladding till the desired weight can be managed.  The approach, cost, and work involved all are dependent on how much / little of the solution should be visible when the picture is removed.  Tack welding a plate over the skin, removing the skin and replacing it with reinforced skin, reconstructing the panel with internal framing, and effectively rebuilding the entire wall of panels (including better framing) all are solutions, depending on the weight, cost, and time one is willing to spend.

In construction, there is a way if money is no object.  I'd advise considering custom solutions, as the costs go up faster than the value of the solutions.